# Asp.net add content automatically

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, parameters

For my site I want to have a page which I will call programatically to add content. 
The parameters that I will need are some strings and the content of a file. 
I will invoke that with WebRequest object form .net. 
How can I send the string parameters and the content of a file in a post request and read them in the aspx page?

Is there any possibility to send an array of objects like to a web service?

Thanks,
Radu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need a page to get some content, you can use `QueryString` to pass your parameters to your page. The easiest way is to use `QueryString`.

Also you can send your parameters as form values (simply input elements), and try to get them in your content page using `Request` object.

Comment: And how can I send a binary file in the query string?

Comment: @Radu D: I thought you want to send only the name of a file that exists in your server. Then the only way looks like sending your file as a form element to server.